# Project has triggered a breakpoint followed by _BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID(pHeap->nBlockUse)

Tags: c++

I have an ADT collection defined over a self implemented dynamic vector.
When i'm trying to put element in the ADT, "Project has triggered a breakpoint." exception occurs in visual studio or "application stopped working..." in code blocks. 
I think the methods are straightforward, can someone point what i am doing wrong? Thanks.

Code for Dynamic vector:

```
#ifndef DYNAMICVECTOR_H
#define DYNAMICVECTOR_H

template<class T>class DynamicVector{
public:
DynamicVector(int dim){
    this->vect = new T[dim];
    this->dim = dim;
    this->index = -1;
}

~DynamicVector(){
    delete [] vect;
}
void addElement(T elem){
    index++;
    this->vect[index] = elem;
}
private:
    T *vect;
    int index, dim;
};
#endif
```

code for ADT Collection:

```
#ifndef COLLECTION_H
#define COLLECTION_H

#include "DynamicVector.h"
#include "IteratorD.h"

template<class T>class Collection{
private:
DynamicVector<T> vect;

public:
Collection(){
    this->vect = DynamicVector<T>(10);
}

void add(T elem){
    this->vect.addElement(elem);
}

};

#endif
```

and main.cpp:

```
#include "DynamicVector.h"
#include "Collection.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void main()
{
Collection<int> col = Collection<int>();
    col.add(1);
    col.add(1);
    col.add(1);

    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Why not just use `std::vector`?

Comment: It is a task, i have to do it like this, with an adt over a self defined dynamic array.

Comment: Ok. What's in `#include "IteratorD.h"` ?

Comment: it is an iterator that i have to use in order to iterate over the adt. But i don't get to that part. The problem occurs at the adding part.

Comment: This doesn't actually compile for me as-is. `error: no matching function for call to ‘DynamicVector<int>::DynamicVector()’`

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about debugging.

Answer (score 3):

Your code does not compile with **gcc 4.8.1** (without any flag), for 2 reasons :

1. `void main()` generates an error. It should be `int main()`.
2. Since you're not using the initialization list in `Collection` constructor, a default constructor in `DynamicVector` is required, which can't be auto-generated because you provide an overloaded constructor taking an int.
   Change it to `Collection() : vect(10) {}`

And now your code compiles and runs fine. And if Visual Studio compiled it fine as provided in your question, run away from it, quickly.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here I believe comes down to how members are being initialized. What you need to do is use the initialization list syntax to initialize the members for `Collection` and `DynamicVector`. For more information I would direct you to this c++ FAQ item: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/init-lists.html

```
template<class T>
class DynamicVector{
    public:
        DynamicVector(int dim):
            dim(dim),
            index(-1)        
        {
            this->vect = new T[dim];
        }

        ~DynamicVector(){
            delete [] vect;
        }
        void addElement(T elem){
            index++;
            this->vect[index] = elem;
        }
    private:
        T *vect;
        int dim;
        int index;
};

template<class T>
class Collection{
    private:
        DynamicVector<T> vect;

    public:
        Collection():
            vect(10) //use this way to initialize vect
        {
        }

        void add(T elem){
            this->vect.addElement(elem);
        }
};

int main(){
Collection<int> col = Collection<int>();
    col.add(1);
    col.add(1);
    col.add(1);

    return 0;
}
```

Also please use `int main()` and not `void main()`, see http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/main-returns-int.html

Comment: Why using the copy-constructor here ? Simply use `Collection() : vect(10) {}`.

Comment: @Chnossos for the sake of explanation I didn't want to change the code syntax too much but you are indeed correct that it is the better way of going about it.

Answer (score 0):

```
Collection(){
    this->vect = DynamicVector<T>(10);
}
```

this is the faulty code. Because you are creating a local object of DynamicVector(10) which is then assigned to the variable this->vect using default-copy-constructor generated by the compiler. This default-copy-constructor will do an memberwise assignment. And after that the local object instance is destroyed which will invoke the destructor of DynamicVector. Which in term will free the memory by calling delete[].

So now the memory whose address is held by this->vect in the DynamicVector is invalid.
And later when you are trying to access it by dereferencing the pointer, you are getting the error.

Solution:

```
template<class T>class Collection{
private:
DynamicVector<T> * vect;

public:
Collection(){
    this->vect = new DynamicVector<T>(10);
}

~Collection() {
    delete this->vect;
}

void add(T elem){
    this->vect->addElement(elem);
}
};
```

Comment: This constructor should not even compile. And avoid solutions using pointers and memory allocation if possible, you should just tell him to use the initialization list like `Collection():vect(10){}`.

Comment: @Chnossos ahh sorry you are right. in the previous example DynamicVector<T> vect; won't compile.
I just tried to quickly edit fix the problem and initialization-list didn't come to my mind (i work with gcc version which does not play well with it)

Comment: _(i work with gcc version which does not play well with it)_ I actually don't really understand this ... I use gcc 4.8.1 so ...

Comment: @Chnossos I am not sure but I think gcc version 4.3 doesn't support initialization list.

Comment: Sounds impossible to me. Aren't you talking about `std::initializer_list` ? I'm talking about [member initializer list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list).

Comment: @Chnossos yes you are right, I was talking about member initializer list, but I seldom used it so I was not sure. It seems that I was wrong. Thanks again.